# Allow a div to cover the whole page instead of the area within the container

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a semi-transparent div cover the whole screen. I tried this:

```
#dimScreen
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

But that doesn't cover the whole screen, it only covers the area within the div.

Comment: Add `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: Is there any update for CSS3 or whatever extensions they have today?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Add `position:fixed`. Then the cover is fixed over the whole screen, also when you scroll.
And add maybe also `margin: 0; padding:0;` so it wont have some space's around the cover.

```
#dimScreen
{
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    top:0;
    left:0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

And if it shouldn't stick on the screen fixed, use `position:absolute;`

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) have also an interesting article about fullscreen property.

**Edit:**
Just came across this answer, so I wanted to add some additional things.
Like [Daniel Allen Langdon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238260/daniel-allen-langdon) mentioned in the comment, add `top:0; left:0;` to be sure, the cover sticks on the very top and left of the screen.

If you want some elements to be at the top of the cover (so it doesn't cover everything), then add `z-index`. The higher the number, the more levels it covers.

Comment: In my experience, I also needed `top: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: Apparently there is a gotcha: if the position:fixed element has an ancestor with a css transform, then it will be fixed relative to that ancestor instead of the viewport. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values

Answer (score 28):

You need to set the parent element to `100%` as well

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyYLE/) (Changed the `background` for demo purpose)

---

Also, when you want to cover entire screen, seems like you want to `dim`, so in this case, you need to use `position: fixed;`

```
#dimScreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100; /* Just to keep it at the very top */
}
```

If that's the case, than you don't need `html, body {height: 100%;}`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/xyYLE/8/)

Comment: Maybe any of the parents have `position:relative`. It will not work. Suggest `position:fixed` instead.

Answer (score 17):

This will do the trick!

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `position:fixed` this way your div will remain over the whole viewable area continuously ..

give your div a class `overlay` and create the following rule in your CSS

```
.overlay{
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/TtL7R/1/

Comment: This is not showing the overlay div to me... Did something change since '13?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#dimScreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#dimScreen{
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply a css-reset to reset all the margins and paddings
like this

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
```

v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
    */

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

You can use various css-resets as you need, normal and use in css

```
 html
 {
  margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 }

body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: How is this relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Set the html and body tags `height` to `100%` and remove the margin around the body:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px; /* Remove the margin around the body */
}
```

Now set the `position` of your div to `fixed`:

```
#dimScreen
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);

    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    z-index: 1000; /* Now the div will be on top */
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/F3LHW/

Answer (score 0):

please try with setting margin and padding to 0 on body.

```
<body style="margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">
```