# Div overlay does not apply to entire page, when there is scroll

Tags: html

I want to make an overlay div cover the ENTIRE page... NOT just the viewport. my html code is as below

```
<div id="overlayview" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1004; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Use position:fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow a div to cover the whole page instead of the area within the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588835/allow-a-div-to-cover-the-whole-page-instead-of-the-area-within-the-container)