# Multiple Pages in Single HTML with continuity between pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, hashtag

I found this code below (which i updated a little), which is sort of what I want, although If I am on the English section I want it to link to the english section on another webspage by passing the page ref in the link.

I am basically HOPING to have a french and english version of text in one html file, the user being able to select the language, so if you are in the english version it would link to the english version of the next page, the french version would link to the french version in the next page.  The links would link using a hashtag for example

> combinedhtml.htm/#English

or

> combinedhtml.htm/#French

Hope that makes sense.

Where ever possible it would be best to have the very minimal of javascript (as I am not good with Javascript), prefer to do as much as possible in HTML5/CSS.

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="English">
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('French','English');">Show French Version</a>
    <br>
    My ENGLISH Content which should link to English content on linked pages
    <a href="Page2#English"> link to another page showing the correct version (English)</a> 
  </div>

  <div id="French" style="display:none">
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('English','French');">Show English Version</a>
    <br>
    My FRENCH Content which should link to English content on linked pages
    <a href="Page2#French"> link to another page showing the correct version (French)</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want minimal JavaScript, you may be interested to know that this can be done in modern browsers with [no JavaScript at all](http://www.alohci.net/static/richardiii.html#English)

Comment: OK, I like that :) - Its clever, although I don't quite understand why it works but it does... Much appreciated.

Comment: OK Alohci, is it possible to have the french / English sections defined by css class rather than ids? I could have the whole page inside the sections, but it would be nice if i could highlight 3 or 4 sections which can be changed from english to french.  I was thinking about the main menu seperate and then seperate main seciton but that might be a 'chunk' of code that was identical between both versions and it would better not to duplicate if possible. for example code for photos etc

Comment: Not like that, no. It was very much the demonstration of a trick, which is why it's a comment, not an answer. For anything more flexible, stick to JS solutions.

Comment: as its a trick...  is it frowned upon?  Its a nice trick, do you know if its compatible with IE, Moz etc?

Comment: Can it work by not adding any #id to show english and then show the french by having #French? eg

French would be
richardiii.html#French

English would be
richardiii.htm

Comment: Yes, providing that the English section comes last in the HTML. Then replace `section { display:none; } section:target { display:block; }` with `#French { display:none; } #French:target { display:block; } #English { display:block; } :target ~ #English { display:none; }` and all the #English fragment identifiers can be removed from the links.

Comment: I had a think about your question about multiple blocks by class. Rather than use the class attribute you could (and should) use the lang attribute. If you add an anchor separate from the content at the start of body, and then apply css to the lang elements relative to that, you can achieve the multiple blocks you desire. This [revised link](http://www.alohci.net/static/lang/kinglear.html) only shows a single block for each language but would work for multiple blocks.

Comment: Thanks for that, There is a 'chunk' of Javascript in the file at the start of the body.  Is that needed/what is it?  I took it out and it still seems to work?? - Thank you so much for all your work.

Comment: There's no JS in my source. Are you seeing something added by a browser plug-in?

Comment: Probably...  I deleted it anyway... I have spent the morning on it and it has been going well thank you...  [link](http://www.poipleshadow.com/Websites/Celine/#) is the page I have created, you use the flags in the top right to change from English to French...  Just the one pge as an example to show my friend..  Thanks for all your help, please shout if I have done something stupid in the example.

Comment: the blue and red is just to help me know what bits were french/english easily...

Comment: OK, I have another query for you...  Is it possible to have a ID linked as well as using the language ID's?  Have a look here [Sample Page](http://www.poipleshadow.com/Websites/Celine/Links), if I use a link to a ID it overwrites the language tag (so it always links to the English version.  The link I am trying to get to work is on the right hand saide called **LINK INSIDE DOCUMENT**.

Comment: If you use the fragment identifier for the language then you can't use it for anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alohci, has kindly been helping me solve my problem with having two languages on one page and he came up with this great trick.  It works really well and I am using it here

http://www.poipleshadow.com/Websites/Celine/index.htm

Just use the flags (top right hand corner) to swap languages..

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Neat Trick by Alohci */
[lang=fr] { display:none; }
[lang=en] { display:block; }
#French:target ~ [lang=fr], #French:target ~ * [lang=fr] { display:block; }
:target ~ [lang=en], :target ~ * [lang=en] { display:none; }
```

HTML

```
<!-- DO NOT CHANGE THIS --> 
<a id="French"></a>
<h1 lang="en">English Title only shown when you add lang="en"</h1>
<h1 lang="fr">French  Title only shown when you add lang="fr"</h1>
<p lang="en">English text to go with the title, this is not shown on the French  version</p>
<p lang="fr">French  text to go with the title, this is not shown on the English version</p>
<p> This text is shown on both as it doesn't state that it is either French or English </p
```

Thanks to Alohci for his assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Page2` would work the same way as `Page1`

but you would add

```
<script>
window.onload=show
window.addEventListener("hashchange", show, false);
</script>
```

to show the English / French Div when the page was loaded initially

**Edit**

your show function would look like:

```
function show() {
  var shown = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
  document.getElementById('English').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('French').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  return false;
 }
```

and here is the modified html

```
<div id="English">
    <a href="Page2#French">Show French Version</a>
    <br>
    My ENGLISH Content which should link to English content on linked pages
    <a href="Page2#English"> link to another page showing the correct version (English)</a> 
  </div>

  <div id="French" style="display:none">
    <a href="Page2#Englsh">Show English Version</a>
    <br>
    My FRENCH Content which should link to English content on linked pages
    <a href="Page2#French"> link to another page showing the correct version (French)</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using the 'trick' provided by Alohci, which seems good, might have a look at this later, thanks for the reply