# Is a bilingual site with CSS & JS a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, multilingual

I want to build a bilingual site with about 5 pages (a portfolio-type page, with short descriptions).

It's a personal webpage with an "About Me" page, "Links" and "Publications". There is definitely no need for more than two languages and no need for more than 5 pages. The site will be hosted on some university website, which means that the requirements for the server should be very low. Also, it will be maintained by someone without programming skills.

I read through [this forum discussion](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1165136-how-to-make-a-html5css3-website-multilingual-with-1-click/), where all are suggesting to do a translation "server-side", rather than "client-side".

My site will be very small, even most content being monolingual. The "translation" is really only intended for easily navigating the material in two languages. That is, only menu entries and short descriptions will be in two languages.

Is a simple CSS + JS solution, hiding and showing two languages via JS, really such a bad idea?

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="english">Events</li>
  <li class="portuguese">Eventos</li>
</ul>
```

I see one major benefit with this approach: it is easy to maintain, even just using a simple text editor.

Comment: You might be interested in this question: [Multiple Pages in Single HTML with continuity between pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591099/multiple-pages-in-single-html-with-continuity-between-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's semantically correct and the site is small enough to be able to manage, there shouldn't be an issue.

By semantically correct I mean does the HTML document make sense if you read it on it's own? If you order the source code how you would expect a bilingual document to be given to you, then the answer is yes.

I would use the lang attribute instead of a CSS class to decide what to show/hide, e.g.:

```
<body class="english-site">
  <div lang="en"><p>English</p></div>
  <div lang="de"><p>German</p></div>  
</body>
```

and

```
body.english-site [lang]:not([lang=en]) {
  display: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/penx/pen/uihyK

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to `lang`. I guess, the CSS is better left as `body.english-site [lang=de] { display: none; }`, otherwise it does not work well with elements that don't need translation, i.e. should be displayed in either language.

Comment: Using this technique means other languages can be added in future and it will automatically hide them. It only applies the `display:none` to elements that have a lang attribute, so if you want to show something in all languages then I guess don't add a lang tag.

Answer (score 2):

It will be mostly a patch and won't be scalable in the end. You should really look into the PHP gettext extension. It works something like this: each string that you want translated you output it from php .

Comment: Good point. Although he mentions that it is very small in size, who  knows...down the road they might want to add more and simply duplicating the HTML for all 5 languages isn't scalable.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to: [**Internationalization** | **globalization** | **localization** ] one of the most popular standards is [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) which is all about from coding perspective to create a "resource dictionary".

Different libraries have implemented to implement standard and their principles covers from translations to conversions when it comes to things like currencies, dates and numbers.

For instance [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/blob/master/spec/i18n_spec.js) suggests this structure:

```
I18n.translations = {
            en: {
                hello: "Hello World!"               
            },
            "pt-BR": {
                hello: "Olá Mundo!"
            },
            "de": {
                hello: "Hallo Welt!"
            },
            "nb": {
                hello: "Hei Verden!"
            }
        };

   I18n.t("hello", {locale: "en"});    //returns  "Hello World!"
   I18n.t("hello", {locale: "pt-BR"}); //returns "Olá Mundo!"
```

There is a [JQuery plug-in](https://github.com/recurser/jquery-i18n/blob/master/specs/jquery.i18n.spec.js) that may help as well:

```
$.i18n.load({ a_key: 'translated string %2$s - %1$s' });
$.i18n._('a_key', ['order', 'in'])); //returns 'translated string in - order'
```

To define the structure it is recommendable to select first the base Framework(that suits better your needs) and follow the best practices from the community. This will make the process of decisions more guided and backed up in the experience of a community.

[How to dynamically change language using jquery-i18n-properties and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15637059/1959948)

Angular also implements i18n and allows to switch languages at runtime:

Doing something like:

```
$translate.use('es');
```

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html

Comment: Does this work without JS enabled? My no-brainer solution will show the default language by default and only hide the default language to show the other language when JS is enabled.

Comment: @Earthliŋ no, this is a js solution. If lack of js is  required then a server side solution is effectively the smart and scalable solution short of some crazy CSS solution.

Comment: @zero298 I edited my OP to clarify that I don't need a scalable solution and that I need a solution, which demands very little of the server and the maintainer, both for updating and moving the site.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

If your site's language requirements never grow beyond what you've described, it's not a terrible idea.

Keep in mind: if you ever want to go further with your translation, you're going to have to start from scratch with server-side translation.