# header and footer on multiple pages using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call header.html and footer.html in every page of html using javascript. I tried the
code [Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-include-multiple-html-pages), but this is not working for me

Here is the same code,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hi</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$("#header").load("header.html"); 
$("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div><br />
<div id="content">
  Main Content
</div><br />
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I downloaded jquery-1.11.1.min.js from this http://jquery.com/download/ site. Please, help me to correct this code.

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-include-multiple-html-pages

Comment: Can you update your post with your current file structure? And does the console give you any errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple distinct pages in one HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211128/multiple-distinct-pages-in-one-html-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in a [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#header").load("header.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
</script>
```

Otherwise your code will execute before `#header` and `#footer` are available.

Comment: Hi, this is working with mozilla but not with chrome

Comment: Hi, I check the console. Here is the error                              XMLHttpRequest cannot load header.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. index.html:1
header.html loaded

Comment: It´s not an issue with this code - it´s because you are using chrome with file URLs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-allow-origin-for-file

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a document ready block

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#header').load('header.html', function () {
    console.log('header.html loaded')
  });
  $('#footer').load('footer.html', function () {
    console.log('footer.html loaded')
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi, this is working with mozilla but not with chrome –

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your DOM is not loaded when you call the script to load the elements.

Jquery cant find the $("#header") and #footer because the DOM is not ready.

Try this just above the `</body>` tag:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("#header").load("header.html"); 
 $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is working with mozilla but not with chrome –